# CIcyano GEE equation

Tags: google-earth-engine

I've been attempting to format the CIcyano equation as an expression in GEE, while utilizing Sentinel-3 OLCI data.  I've gotten the code to run, but am unsure if it's truly formatted properly, specifically in regard to incorporating top-of-atmosphere reflectance values.

CIcyano

= 2 − 1 + (3 − 1 ) × (2−1 / 3−1)

I've tested my resulting code (shown below) at various locations with known HABs but have been met with mixed results.  Any recommendations?

Attempted CIcyano Expression is as follows:

```
var cyano_exp = '(Oa8-Oa7+(Oa10-Oa7)*((Oa8-Oa7)/(Oa10-Oa7)))';
var cyano_img = ee.Image(bands).expression({
  expression:cyano_exp,
  map: {
  'Oa7':bands.select('Oa07_radiance'),
  'Oa8':bands.select('Oa08_radiance'),
  'Oa10':bands.select('Oa10_radiance')}}).rename('cyano_out');
```

**Full Code Below**

```
Map.centerObject(anna, 11);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S3/OLCI')
.filterDate('2020-10-01', '2020-10-07')
.filterBounds(anna);

print(dataset);

var bands = dataset.select(['Oa07_radiance','Oa08_radiance','Oa10_radiance'])
.min()
// Convert to radiance units.
.multiply(ee.Image([0.00879161,0.00876539,0.00773378]));

print(bands);

var cyano_exp = '(Oa8-Oa7+(Oa10-Oa7)*((Oa8-Oa7)/(Oa10-Oa7)))';
var cyano_img = ee.Image(bands).expression({
  expression:cyano_exp,
  map: {
  'Oa7':bands.select('Oa07_radiance'),
  'Oa8':bands.select('Oa08_radiance'),
  'Oa10':bands.select('Oa10_radiance')}}).rename('cyano_out');
Map.addLayer(cyano_img, {min: -0.1, max: 0.1, gamma: 1.5}, 'cyano_output');

print(cyano_img);

var clippedBand = cyano_img.clip(anna) //ClipGeometry can any geometry or feature or shapfile
Map.addLayer(clippedBand, {min: -0.5, max: 0.5, gamma: 1.5},'Clipped Band');

var resultBand = clippedBand.mask(clippedBand.mask().eq(1))
Map.addLayer(resultBand, {min: -0.1, max: 0.1, gamma: 1.5}, 'only whole pixels Band');
```

Comment: Please share the full code.

Comment: Full code has now been shared, sorry about that.